# Common lisp error , not binding variables

Tags: common-lisp, slime

I am following Practical Common Lisp. I have followed the example to the tee. When I compile in Emacs <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> I get the following error with this code.

```
(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
  (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped ripped))

(defvar *db* nil)
(defun add-record (cd)(push cd db))
```

> WARNING: in ADD-RECORD : DB is neither declared nor bound,
>            it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.

I can't understand what is going wrong. It cant be the code because I have tried in both clisp and sbcl, both get similar errors. Why is this occurring? Could my set-up be wrong?

Comment: 'c-c c-c' only compiles one form, the one where the cursor is. Make sure you compile all forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You made a copy error from this [text](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html):

```
(defun add-record (cd) (push cd *db*))
```

where `*db*` (mind the `*` signs) refers to the previous

```
(defvar *db* nil)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help.... I still get an error... I pasted that code after playing around to try make it work... If I use the terminal I dont get the same error, only in slime:  warning: 
    undefined variable: *DB*... that is with the correction you gave... Is it possible that my setup is corrupt?

Comment: Ok... So my functions and variables were not loading correctly. I was naming my files with a space and didnt load into the repl at first then compile... some how this has taken away the issue...

Comment: @CuriousLambda Glad you sorted it out!